# Blob pdf rendering giving error Invalid XRef stream header

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, pdf

I am trying to display a pdf file from my server on my web app through Angular Blob but I am receiving some errors there. I have been stuck with this for too long and tried others things which are not working too. Please suggest.
My Spring controller returns byte[]:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showpdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/octet-stream")
        @ResponseBody
        public byte[] showPDFFile(@RequestBody FilePath filePath, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
                  return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);             
    }
```

My angular code:

```
$http.post('/showpdf',{responseType: 'arrayBuffer'}).success(
                            function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                                   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                                   $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

                            });
```

My HTML page:

```
<div>
    <object data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;"></object>
</div>
```

The pdf window is coming but it does not show any data and keeps on loading in the toolbar(See attached) and the the following error is coming in browser tools.

```
Error: Invalid XRef stream header
pdf.worker.js (line 250)
<System>

XRef_readXRef@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3693:13
XRef_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3289:23
PDFDocument_setup@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2484:7
PDFDocument_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2371:7
LocalPdfManager_ensure/<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1934:20
LocalPdfManager_ensure@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1929:1
BasePdfManager_ensureDoc@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1861:14
loadDocument/</<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:33208:11

pdf.worker.js (line 252)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
<System>
PDF 0d3cdf6286f2947410f0d270a249f816 [1.4 iText 2.1.3 (by lowagie.com)      kSar Version:5.0.6] (PDF.js: 1.0.1149)
 Error: Bad uncompressed block length in flate stream
pdf.worker.js (line 250)
<System>

FlateStream_readBlock@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:31244:9
DecodeStream_getByte@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:30882:9
Lexer_nextChar@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:30125:34
Lexer@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:30067:5
EvaluatorPreprocessor@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:12105:30
PartialEvaluator_getOperatorList@resource://pdf.js/build     /pdf.worker.js:10616:26
Page_getOperatorList/pageListPromise<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2216:16

pdf.worker.js (line 252)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
```

I tried hardcoding this pdf, it renders fine.

Comment: is `arraybuffer` in `{responseType: 'arrayBuffer'}` shall be all lowercase?

Comment: @async5 : that resolved by issue, can you post it as answer so that I can accept it as correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using 'arraybuffer' instead of 'arrayBuffer' as the responseType parameter shall solve the issue:

```
$http.post('showpdf',{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success(
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!